On track with my travel agent
"Hey Pat, thanks for arranging this day trip on the railroad for our scout troop."
"My pleasure, friend. My friend at Union Pacific owes me a favor. I love the sound of the horn and the feel of the track passing underneath."
"You even put together an activity for the scouts...that's really above and beyond. What's the destination?"
"I already told you...look at the activity."
"Pat..."

As you may have guessed by now, the activity doesn't say "we're going to Durango", or anything so simple. Nope, it's the weirdest screed I've read since Pat sent me those cursed flags...looks like ChatGPT wrote this inanity:
"Before proceeding, inspect train for a leak in the brake pipe system. Then proceed, releasing air brakes. As you are approaching passenger station, indicate you're backing up. Acknowledge unexpected signal, then inspect train for sticking brakes."
Well, I can't make head or tails of this...can you figure out where we're headed?

The "inanity" is

 a list of instructions for trains with standardized whistle signals.

Before proceeding, inspect train for a leak in the brake pipe system. - short, then long
Then proceed, releasing air brakes. - two long
As you are approaching passenger station, - single short
indicate you're backing up. - three short
Acknowledge unexpected signal - two short
inspect train for sticking brakes. - short, then long

Together,

 these are Morse code, spelling out AMES IA - you're going to the city of Ames, Iowa!


Crushed in detail! Nice work :-)
